# Get Module Address in C# .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I am creating a directx overlay for an esp hack in a game. (I have made several in C++ but wanted to try c#) This method requires me to use a version of directx which is only compatible with .net framework 3.5 or older. I have been using this code to obtain the base address of a specific module:

```
static int GetModuleAddress(string moduleName)
    {
        try
        {
            Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(game.process);

            if (p.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (ProcessModule m in p[0].Modules)
                {
                    if (m.ModuleName == moduleName)
                    {
                        //temp = (int)m.BaseAddress;
                        //return temp;
                        return (int)m.BaseAddress;

                    }
                }
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

This code works fine in framework 4.5.2 (it cycles through nearly 100 different modules and returns the base address of whichever module i'm looking for). But when using the code in 3.5 it only cycles through about 5 modules (none of which are the ones i need) and returns -1.

Why is this caused? Is there another way to obtain a base address of a module?

Comment: Are you executing it with elevated privileges? Also, there's no need to use FW 3.5, .net4.5 is backwards compatible.

Comment: It is ONLY compatible with 3.5 or less. I assure you. Spent about an hour on that headache today. I wouldn't be using 3.5 if it wasn't necessary. Otherwise I wouldn't have this problem to begin with.      What elevated privileges would i need? It works fine in 4.5.2 but not 3.5. As stated in op.

Comment: Anyway, are you executing it with elevated privileges? if not then the process may not be able to access another process information.

Comment: Yes, i am. It is accessing the other processes information. Somewhat. Like i said...It reads about 5 modules instead of the usual 100.

Comment: Then there should be some bug on the 3.5 version you're using, you can always use P/Invoke with OpenProcess and EnumProcessModules.

Comment: Would be a much better question if you had documented the 5 modules you see.  But it is guessable, crystal ball says that your program is running in 64-bit mode.  So it sees only a few modules of the 32-bit process, the ones used by the 64-bit emulator in which the 32-bit process runs.  Easy to see by their name, "wow64" is the emulator name.  Use Project > Properties > Build tab > Platform target = x86 to match the bitness of the game.

Comment: That was the problem. Wow i would have bet money i already changed that... strange. Thanks very much man i won't overlook it again ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're only seeing 5 modules is because you're using an x86 program to parse the modules of an x64 process.  If you're making a program that interacts with the memory of an external process you should always compile it for the target processes's architecture.  This will save you lots of headache.

Use IntPtr for addresses and offsets and compile both x86 and x64 versions, then use the correct version for each type of target process, this will ensure the minimal amount of problems.

In addition, make sure you always run as administrator.